# Creating multiple invisible windows with different parameters in Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

## Description

I am trying to use invisible windows as tasks/threads in Electron.
First I create a number of invisible windows in a for-loop in the main process. Each window sends an event `dom-is-ready` back. As soon as this even is received in the main process, an event with a parameter (a path) is sent back to the window, which then creates an array and sends that array back to the main process.

## Code

### Main Process

```
for(let i = 0; i < paths.length; i++){
    invPfWins[i] = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 400,
        height: 400,
        show: false
    });

    invPfWins[i].loadURL(invisPath);

    invPfWins[i].webContents.on('did-finish-load', function () {
        invPfWins[i].show();
    });
    invPfWins[i].webContents.openDevTools();

}

let i = 0;

ipcMain.on('dom-is-ready', function (event) {
    invPfWins[i].webContents.send('start-read-files', paths[i], i++);
});

ipcMain.on('files-read-done', function (event, output, id) {
    console.log(output);
    pfLists[id] = output;
});
```

- `paths` is an array of paths that will be sent to the invisible windows
- `invPfWins` stores the invisible windows that are created

### Invisible Window

```
ipc.on('start-read-files', function (event, ppath, id) {
    console.log("start signal received");
    let retVal = readFiles(ppath);

    ipc.send('files-read-done', retVal, id)
    window.close()
});

ipc.send('dom-is-ready');
console.log("dom-is-ready sent");
```

## Behaviour

The program does not create an error but most of the time some of the invisible (not yet invisible) windows do not terminate and also don't send results. All invisible windows send the `dom-is-ready` event but those that don't terminate do not receive the `start-read-files` event. I think that is because of a race condition, that after I created the windows in the for loop it can happen that the windows don't send the `dom-is-ready` event in the order they were created in.
I also tried to put the code that listens for the `dom-is-ready` event into the for-loop but then I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Exception:
Error: Object has been destroyed
    at Error (native)
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous>
```

## Question

Is my guess that this race condition is the problem right? And how can I solve that?
I also feel like this is not a good way of doing that, is there a better way in Electron to spawn tasks/threads like these (I also tried web workers but the node.js modules did not work there)?